# Checar o radio button clicando na div, porem a div nao aparece

Tags: php, jquery

Eu tenho um form com 3 opções, 3 radio.

Se a opção 1 for checada, aparece o form1 e assim sucessivamente.

Cada radio esta dentro de uma div, ou seja, se eu clicar na div, ele checka o radio.

O meu problema eh, se eu clico no radio... o form correspodente aparece, mas se eu clico na div, ele checka o radio mas nao aparece o form.

Meu html e js estão assim, abaixo:

### HTML

```
<form id=form>
<div id=conteiner>
 <input type=radio name=opcao value="A" id=form1>
</div>

<div id=conteiner>
 <input type=radio name=opcao value="B" id=form2>
</div>

<div id=conteiner>
 <input type=radio name=opcao value="C" id=form3>
</div>
</form>

<form action="form1.php" method=post id=A style="display:none;">
<input type=text>teste1
</form>

<form action="form2.php" method=post id=B style="display:none;">
<input type=text>teste2
</form>

<form action="form3.php" method=post id=C style="display:none;">
<input type=text>teste3
</form>
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#form-planos').change(function() {
    if ($('#form1').prop('checked')) {
        $('#A').show();
        $('#B').hide();
        $('#C').hide();
    } else {
        if ($('#form2').prop('checked')) {
        $('#B').show();
        $('#A').hide();
        $('#C').hide();
       } else {
        $('#A').hide();
        $('#B').hide();
        $('#C').show();
       }   
    }
   });
});

$("#conteiner").live("click",function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is('input:radio')) return;

    var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='radio']");

    if( checkbox.attr("checked") == "" ){
       checkbox.attr("checked","true");
    } else {
       checkbox.attr("checked","");
    }
    $("div.assinatura").click(function () {

        $('input:radio').attr('checked',false);

    });   
});

$(function(){
    $('table').on('click', 'td', function(){
        $(this).parent().children().removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

O `id` do formulário estava apenas `form`, enquanto a chamada do JavaScript estava **`form-planos`**. Além disso, acho também que vc deveria utilizar `classe` neste caso, ao invés de `id`.

E não tenho certeza se é isso que você precisa, mas dá pra incluir um `label` dentro da `div`, daí todo o texto do `label` servirá para selecionar o `radio` e abrir o `form`.

Fiz um exemplo verificável à partir do seu código, utilizando `classe` ao invés de `id`, veja abaixo em **"Executar trecho de código"**:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.form-planos').change(function() {
                if ($('#form1').prop('checked')) {
                    $('#A').show();
                    $('#B').hide();
                    $('#C').hide();
                } else {
                    if ($('#form2').prop('checked')) {
                        $('#B').show();
                        $('#A').hide();
                        $('#C').hide();
                    } else {
                        $('#A').hide();
                        $('#B').hide();
                        $('#C').show();
                    }
                }
            });
        });


        $(".conteiner").live("click",function(event) {
            var target = $(event.target);
            if (target.is('input:radio')) return;

            var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='radio']");

            if( checkbox.attr("checked") == "" ){
                checkbox.attr("checked","true");
            } else {
                checkbox.attr("checked","");
            }
            $("div.assinatura").click(function () {

                $('input:radio').attr('checked',false);

            });
        });

        $(function(){
            $('table').on('click', 'td', function(){
                $(this).parent().children().removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formss" class="form-planos">
    <div class="conteiner" id="1">
        <label id="formum">
        <input type="radio" name="opcao" value="A" id="form1">Label clicável</label>
    </div>

    <div class="conteiner" id="2">
        <label id="formum2">
        <input type="radio" name="opcao" value="B" id="form2">Label clicável</label>
    </div>

    <div class="conteiner" id="3">
        <label id="formum3">
        <input type="radio" name="opcao" value="C" id="form3">Label clicável</label>
    </div>
</form>
<br>

<form action="form1.php" method="post" id="A" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text">teste1
</form>

<form action="form2.php" method="post" id="B" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text">teste2
</form>

<form action="form3.php" method="post" id="C" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text">teste3
</form>
```

Espero que seja útil.

Comment: Funcionou irmao.. muito obrigado. O pulo do gato acho que foi o label :) vlw mesmo

Comment: Eduardo, veja neste link http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/23400 como aceitar a resposta, marcando assim a pergunta como resolvida.